# Bootstrap dropdown doesn't work in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

My application.js looks this way:

```
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Dropdown works fine in dev env(no need to show it)

This is the first 2 lines of custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

rails 4.2 rc2

How to make the dropdown work in production?

Comment: Does it work if you require bootstrap after jquery?

Comment: On a side note, the major release of [Rails 4.2.0](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html) is available :)

Comment: @ptd This way it stops working even in dev env

Comment: What javascript errors, if any, show up in the console either on page load or when you click the drop down?

Comment: I can't find any errors in logs

Comment: How is it not working? Does it show up and you just can't click it open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I got it working in production.
What I did:

placed requires this way:

```
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

and added this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    });
```

In dev env, dropdowns work just by including `//= require bootstrap` to `application.js`
But in production they don't.

**UP 10/2015**

This structure fixes the problem

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.turbolinks    
//= require bootstrap 
//= require turbolinks
```

Comment: @doug the last thing you can do is removing the turbolinks completely)

Comment: thanks for the note.  i removed the turbo links like in the application.js and restarted the web server, then cleared my browser cache. still having the same issue.  this started happening after upgrading from rails 4.1.8 to 4.2.0.  Been banging my head against the wall for two full days now!

Comment: remove all " 'data-turbolinks-track' => true" from application.html.erb in layouts folder.